# google finance new site quote scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-finance

I have been trying to scrape quotes from the new [google finance site](http://google.com/finance?q=AAPL) with this code that I wrote.

```
import urllib
import re
import time
import requests

def get_quote(symbol):
    base_url = 'http://google.com/finance?q='+ symbol
    content = urllib.urlopen(base_url).read()
    m = re.search('id="ref_(.*?)">(.*?)<', content)
    print m
    if m:
        quote = m.group(2)
        print quote
    else:
        quote = 'no quote available for: ' + symbol
    return quote
while True:
    get_quote('AAPL')
    time.sleep(10)
```

When I try to print the content variable, it tells me that my request was blocked.

How do I get over this by implementing headers?

Edit:
working code:

```
from lxml import html
import time
import requests

def get_quote(symbol):
    url = 'http://google.com/finance?q='+ symbol

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    price = tree.xpath('//*[@id="knowledge-finance-wholepage__entity-summary"]/div/g-card-section/div/g-card-section/div[1]/span[1]/span/span[1]/text()')
    print price

while True:
    get_quote('AAPL')
    time.sleep(10)
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Did you try using a fake `User-Agent`?

Comment: If you want to scrape not just the price but the whole Google Finance Ticker page, there's a [scrape Google Finance Ticker Quote Data in Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-finance-ticker-quote-data-in-python/#what_will_be_scraped) blog post at SerpApi with line-by line explanation. If you don't need an explanation you can [check the full code in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Finance-Ticker-Quote-in-Python#main.py) on replit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the google finance API instead of the URL which should be used by a user -

Change your url -

```
base_url = 'https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:' + symbol + '&output=json'
```

Here is the content you now have to parse -

```
[{
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "exchange": "NASDAQ",
    "id": "22144",
    "t": "AAPL",
    "e": "NASDAQ",
    "name": "Apple Inc.",
    "f_reuters_url": "http:\u002F\u002Fstocks.us.reuters.com\u002Fstocks\u002Fratios.asp?rpc=66\u0026symbol=AAPL.O",
    "f_recent_quarter_date": "Q4 (Dec \u002717)",
    "f_annual_date": "2017",
    "f_ttm_date": "2016",
    "financials": [{
            "f_type": "Income\u0026nbsp\u003BStatement",
            "url": "http://www.google.com/finance?fstype=ii&q=NASDAQ:AAPL",
            "f_figures": [{
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "88,293.00",
                    "annual": "229,234.00",
                    "ttm": "215,639.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "88,293.00",
                    "annual": "229,234.00",
                    "ttm": "215,639.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "54,381.00",
                    "annual": "141,048.00",
                    "ttm": "131,376.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "33,912.00",
                    "annual": "88,186.00",
                    "ttm": "84,263.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "4,231.00",
                    "annual": "15,261.00",
                    "ttm": "14,194.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "3,407.00",
                    "annual": "11,581.00",
                    "ttm": "10,045.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "62,019.00",
                    "annual": "167,890.00",
                    "ttm": "155,615.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "26,274.00",
                    "annual": "61,344.00",
                    "ttm": "60,024.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "38.00",
                    "annual": "-133.00",
                    "ttm": "-1,195.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "27,030.00",
                    "annual": "64,089.00",
                    "ttm": "61,372.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "22,665.00",
                    "annual": "48,351.00",
                    "ttm": "45,687.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "22,665.00",
                    "annual": "48,351.00",
                    "ttm": "45,687.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "20,065.00",
                    "annual": "48,351.00",
                    "ttm": "45,687.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "22,665.00",
                    "annual": "48,351.00",
                    "ttm": "45,687.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "20,065.00",
                    "annual": "48,351.00",
                    "ttm": "45,687.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "5,157.79",
                    "annual": "5,251.69",
                    "ttm": "5,500.28"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "4.39",
                    "annual": "9.21",
                    "ttm": "8.31"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "0.63",
                    "annual": "2.40",
                    "ttm": "2.18"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "4.39",
                    "annual": "9.21",
                    "ttm": "8.31"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f_type": "Balance\u0026nbsp\u003BSheet",
            "url": "http://www.google.com/finance?fstype=bi&q=NASDAQ:AAPL",
            "f_figures": [{
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "17,962.00",
                    "annual": "12,307.00",
                    "ttm": "11,883.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "49,662.00",
                    "annual": "53,892.00",
                    "ttm": "46,671.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "77,153.00",
                    "annual": "74,181.00",
                    "ttm": "67,155.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "23,440.00",
                    "annual": "17,874.00",
                    "ttm": "15,754.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "50,899.00",
                    "annual": "35,673.00",
                    "ttm": "29,299.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "4,421.00",
                    "annual": "4,855.00",
                    "ttm": "2,132.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "11,337.00",
                    "annual": "13,936.00",
                    "ttm": "8,283.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "143,810.00",
                    "annual": "128,645.00",
                    "ttm": "106,869.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "77,110.00",
                    "annual": "75,076.00",
                    "ttm": "61,245.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-43,431.00",
                    "annual": "-41,293.00",
                    "ttm": "-34,235.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "5,889.00",
                    "annual": "5,717.00",
                    "ttm": "5,414.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "2,149.00",
                    "annual": "2,298.00",
                    "ttm": "3,206.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "207,944.00",
                    "annual": "194,714.00",
                    "ttm": "170,430.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "13,323.00",
                    "annual": "10,162.00",
                    "ttm": "8,757.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "406,794.00",
                    "annual": "375,319.00",
                    "ttm": "321,686.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "62,985.00",
                    "annual": "49,049.00",
                    "ttm": "37,294.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "26,281.00",
                    "annual": "25,744.00",
                    "ttm": "20,951.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "11,980.00",
                    "annual": "11,977.00",
                    "ttm": "8,105.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "6,498.00",
                    "annual": "6,496.00",
                    "ttm": "3,500.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "8,044.00",
                    "annual": "7,548.00",
                    "ttm": "9,156.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "115,788.00",
                    "annual": "100,814.00",
                    "ttm": "79,006.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "103,922.00",
                    "annual": "97,207.00",
                    "ttm": "75,427.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "103,922.00",
                    "annual": "97,207.00",
                    "ttm": "75,427.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "122,400.00",
                    "annual": "115,680.00",
                    "ttm": "87,032.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "548.00",
                    "annual": "31,504.00",
                    "ttm": "26,019.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "46,337.00",
                    "annual": "11,747.00",
                    "ttm": "12,985.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "266,595.00",
                    "annual": "241,272.00",
                    "ttm": "193,437.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "36,447.00",
                    "annual": "35,867.00",
                    "ttm": "31,251.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "104,593.00",
                    "annual": "98,330.00",
                    "ttm": "96,364.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-907.00",
                    "annual": "-26.00",
                    "ttm": "596.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "140,199.00",
                    "annual": "134,047.00",
                    "ttm": "128,249.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "406,794.00",
                    "annual": "375,319.00",
                    "ttm": "321,686.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "5,081.65",
                    "annual": "5,126.20",
                    "ttm": "5,336.17"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f_type": "Cash\u0026nbsp\u003BFlow",
            "url": "http://www.google.com/finance?fstype=ci&q=NASDAQ:AAPL",
            "f_figures": [{
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "20,065.00",
                    "annual": "48,351.00",
                    "ttm": "45,687.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "2,745.00",
                    "annual": "10,157.00",
                    "ttm": "10,505.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-33,737.00",
                    "annual": "5,966.00",
                    "ttm": "4,938.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "1,285.00",
                    "annual": "4,674.00",
                    "ttm": "4,210.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "37,935.00",
                    "annual": "-5,550.00",
                    "ttm": "484.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "28,293.00",
                    "annual": "63,598.00",
                    "ttm": "65,824.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-2,964.00",
                    "annual": "-12,795.00",
                    "ttm": "-13,548.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-10,626.00",
                    "annual": "-33,651.00",
                    "ttm": "-32,429.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-13,590.00",
                    "annual": "-46,446.00",
                    "ttm": "-45,977.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-1,038.00",
                    "annual": "-1,247.00",
                    "ttm": "-1,163.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-3,339.00",
                    "annual": "-12,769.00",
                    "ttm": "-12,150.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-10,095.00",
                    "annual": "-32,345.00",
                    "ttm": "-29,227.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "6,971.00",
                    "annual": "29,014.00",
                    "ttm": "22,057.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-7,501.00",
                    "annual": "-17,347.00",
                    "ttm": "-20,483.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "-",
                    "annual": "-",
                    "ttm": "-"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "7,202.00",
                    "annual": "-195.00",
                    "ttm": "-636.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "623.00",
                    "annual": "2,092.00",
                    "ttm": "1,316.00"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "recent_quarter": "3,551.00",
                    "annual": "11,591.00",
                    "ttm": "10,444.00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "kr_recent_quarter_date": "Q4 (Dec \u002717)",
    "kr_annual_date": "2017",
    "kr_ttm_date": "TTM",
    "keyratios": [{
            "title": "Net profit margin",
            "recent_quarter": "25.67%",
            "annual": "21.09%",
            "ttm": "22.21%"
        },
        {
            "title": "Operating margin",
            "recent_quarter": "29.76%",
            "annual": "26.76%",
            "ttm": "26.87%"
        },
        {
            "title": "EBITD margin",
            "recent_quarter": "",
            "annual": "30.86%",
            "ttm": "31.01%"
        },
        {
            "title": "Return on average assets",
            "recent_quarter": "23.25%",
            "annual": "13.87%",
            "ttm": "14.40%"
        },
        {
            "title": "Return on average equity",
            "recent_quarter": "66.30%",
            "annual": "36.87%",
            "ttm": "38.98%"
        },
        {
            "title": "Employees",
            "recent_quarter": "123,000",
            "annual": "-",
            "ttm": "-"
        }
    ],
    "c": "-0.58",
    "l": "178.39",
    "cp": "-0.32",
    "ccol": "chr",
    "op": "179.10",
    "hi": "180.48",
    "lo": "178.16",
    "vo": "38.93M",
    "avvo": "44.16M",
    "hi52": "180.48",
    "lo52": "136.28",
    "mc": "905.15B",
    "pe": "17.45",
    "fwpe": "",
    "beta": "1.33",
    "eps": "10.22",
    "dy": "1.41",
    "ldiv": "0.63",
    "shares": "5.07B",
    "instown": "63%",
    "eo": "",
    "sid": "us-TRBC:57",
    "sname": "Technology",
    "iid": "us-TRBC:5710601010",
    "iname": "Computer Hardware - NEC",
    "related": [{
            "id": "22144",
            "name": "Apple Inc.",
            "t": "AAPL",
            "e": "NASDAQ",
            "l": "178.39",
            "c": "-0.58",
            "mc": "905.15B",
            "cp": "-0.32",
            "ccol": "chr"
        },
        {
            "id": "358464",
            "name": "Microsoft Corporation",
            "t": "MSFT",
            "e": "NASDAQ",
            "l": "94.20",
            "c": "-1.22",
            "mc": "725.32B",
            "cp": "-1.28",
            "ccol": "chr"
        },
        {
            "id": "694653",
            "name": "Alphabet Inc",
            "t": "GOOGL",
            "e": "NASDAQ",
            "l": "1,117.51",
            "c": "-26.19",
            "mc": "776.61B",
            "cp": "-2.29",
            "ccol": "chr"
        },
        {
            "id": "17154",
            "name": "HP Inc",
            "t": "HPQ",
            "e": "NYSE",
            "l": "23.52",
            "c": "+0.05",
            "mc": "38.70B",
            "cp": "0.19",
            "ccol": "chg"
        },
        {
            "id": "33095",
            "name": "Sony Corp (ADR)",
            "t": "SNE",
            "e": "NYSE",
            "l": "50.27",
            "c": "-0.63",
            "mc": "62.92B",
            "cp": "-1.24",
            "ccol": "chr"
        },
        {
            "id": "664477",
            "name": "Infineon Technologies AG (ADR)",
            "t": "IFNNY",
            "e": "OTCMKTS",
            "l": "27.28",
            "c": "-0.43",
            "mc": "30.65B",
            "cp": "-1.55",
            "ccol": "chr"
        },
        {
            "id": "180086490123759",
            "name": "SAMSUNG ELECTRONIC",
            "t": "SSNNF",
            "e": "OTCMKTS",
            "l": "0.00000",
            "c": "",
            "mc": "",
            "cp": "",
            "ccol": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "4112",
            "name": "Adobe Systems Incorporated",
            "t": "ADBE",
            "e": "NASDAQ",
            "l": "208.82",
            "c": "-3.33",
            "mc": "102.65B",
            "cp": "-1.57",
            "ccol": "chr"
        },
        {
            "id": "5494267",
            "name": "NEC CORP",
            "t": "NIPNF",
            "e": "OTCMKTS",
            "l": "30.00",
            "c": "+4.20",
            "mc": "672.02M",
            "cp": "16.28",
            "ccol": "chg"
        },
        {
            "id": "666634",
            "name": "Synaptics, Incorporated",
            "t": "SYNA",
            "e": "NASDAQ",
            "l": "47.08",
            "c": "-1.13",
            "mc": "1.62B",
            "cp": "-2.34",
            "ccol": "chr"
        },
        {
            "id": "655931",
            "name": "Panasonic Corporation (ADR)",
            "t": "PCRFY",
            "e": "OTCMKTS",
            "l": "15.70",
            "c": "-0.27",
            "mc": "37.69B",
            "cp": "-1.69",
            "ccol": "chr"
        }
    ],
    "summary": [{
        "reuters_url": "http:\u002F\u002Fstocks.us.reuters.com\u002Fstocks\u002FfullDescription.asp?rpc=66\u0026symbol=AAPL.O",
        "address": "1 Apple Park Way, CUPERTINO, CA 95014-0642, United States",
        "phone": "+1-408-9961010",
        "url": "https:\u002F\u002Fwww.apple.com\u002F",
        "overview": "Apple Inc. (Apple) designs, manufactures and markets mobile communication and media devices, personal computers, and portable digital music players, and a variety of related software, services, peripherals, networking solutions, and third-party digital content and applications. The Company\u0027s products and services include iPhone, iPad, Mac, iPod, Apple TV, a portfolio of consumer and professional software applications, the iOS and OS X operating systems, iCloud, and a variety of accessory, service and support offerings. The Company also delivers digital content and applications through the iTunes Store, App StoreSM, iBookstoreSM, and Mac App Store. The Company distributes its products worldwide through its retail stores, online stores, and direct sales force, as well as through third-party cellular network carriers, wholesalers, retailers, and value-added resellers. In February 2012, the Company acquired app-search engine Chomp."
    }],
    "management": [{
            "name": "Art D. Levinson Ph.D.",
            "age": "67",
            "title": "Independent Chairman of the Board"
        },
        {
            "name": "Timothy D. Cook",
            "age": "57",
            "title": "Chief Executive Officer, Director"
        },
        {
            "name": "Luca Maestri",
            "age": "54",
            "title": "Chief Financial Officer, Senior Vice President"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jeff Williams",
            "age": "54",
            "title": "Chief Operating Officer, Senior Vice President"
        },
        {
            "name": "Katherine Adams",
            "age": "53",
            "title": "Senior Vice President, General Counsel"
        },
        {
            "name": "Phil Schiller",
            "age": "57",
            "title": "Senior Vice President - Worldwide Marketing"
        },
        {
            "name": "Angela J. Ahrendts",
            "age": "57",
            "title": "Senior Vice President - Retail"
        },
        {
            "name": "Eddy Cue",
            "age": "54",
            "title": "Senior Vice President - Internet Software and Services"
        },
        {
            "name": "Craig Federighi",
            "age": "48",
            "title": "Senior Vice President - Software Engineering"
        },
        {
            "name": "Daniel J. Riccio Jr.",
            "age": "55",
            "title": "Senior Vice President - Hardware Engineering"
        }
    ],
    "moreresources": [{
            "name": "Estimates",
            "url": "http:\u002F\u002Fwww.marketwatch.com\u002Ftools\u002Fquotes\u002Fsnapshot.asp?symb=AAPL\u0026pg=analyst"
        },
        {
            "name": "SEC Filings",
            "url": "http:\u002F\u002Fgoogle.brand.edgar-online.com\u002F?sym=AAPL"
        },
        {
            "name": "Major Holders",
            "url": "http:\u002F\u002Finvesting.money.msn.com\u002Finvestments\u002Finstitutional-ownership?symbol=AAPL"
        },
        {
            "name": "Options",
            "url": "http:\u002F\u002Fwww.marketwatch.com\u002Ftools\u002Fquotes\u002Foptions1.asp?symb=AAPL"
        },
        {
            "name": "Research",
            "url": "http:\u002F\u002Ffinance.yahoo.com\u002Fq\u002Frr?s=AAPL"
        }
    ],
    "events": []
}]
```

Find more [information here](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/google-finance-apis)

**Note**

I am on Python 3 so I had to change `urllib` to `urllib.request`. You can change that back to see this work.

Comment: But google is going to deprecate  finance.google.com which is where you are pulling the quotes from and the new site is google.com/finance

Comment: Unfortunately, `output=json` is not working anymore.

Comment: You can also [pull Google Finance data directly from Google Sheets using `GOOGLEFINANCE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71913348/15164646) function.